# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Response

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am making an http request to an api then want to console the result using .subscribe but facing this issue as Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise'.

My Angular version is 6.2 and my Typescript version is 2.9 I also googled this and have done needful changes but the outcome is same .

my AuthService file is here

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { CONFIG } from '../config/config'
import { Http } from '@angular/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'


@Injectable()

export class AuthService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    register(name: String, email: String, password: String) {
        this.getConfig()
            .subscribe((response => {
                console.log(response)
            }))
    }

    getConfig() {
        return this.http.post(`${CONFIG.API_URL}/register`, { name: name, email: email, password: password }).toPromise()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove **`toPromise()`**

```
 getConfig() {
        return this.http.post(`${CONFIG.API_URL}/register`, { name: name, email: email, password: password })
    }
```

Comment: It works :-) I think in Angular 6 it is imported by default ? isn`t it ?